# Using variables/parameters in SSIS Package w Python script

Tags: python, sql-server, parameters, ssis, package

I've created a package to do the following:

Truncate Staging Tables -> Run Python Script (this pulls data from an API that populates the staging tables) -> run 3 execute SQL tasks to move last 5 days of data from staging to prod

What I'm trying to do is:

Create Parameters/Variables to allow someone to change the URL, Username, and Password to be editable in SSMS. I'm fairly new to Python and SSIS, so I don't really know what I'm doing; but, this is the line of code that I would be looking to have the variables.

rTotal = requests.get('https://jira.tpp.company.com/rest/zapi/latest/zql/executeSearch?zqlQuery=creationDate%20>%3D%20startOfDay(-5d)&offset=0&maxRecords=1', auth=HTTPBasicAuth(uid, pwd) , verify=False).json()

How would I go about doing this? For the URL, I don't know if it would be better to do something like: 'https://jira.tpp.company.com/rest/zapi/latest/zql/executeSearch?zqlQuery=' + @[User::url]
if thats even how you would do it. For the uid and pwd, can I create variables/parameters like @[User::uid] & @[User::pwd] to replace uid and pwd? Do I need to wrap it in anything or define it somewhere?

Thank in advance for any help you may provide.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're executing this script as an Execute Process Task, with the path to your python.exe in the Executable field and the path to the script itself in the Arguments field.

There's no built-in way to make your SSIS variables available to the Python script the way you could with a C# or VB script task, but you can pass them in at the end of the Arguments field and then grab them using sys.argv as if they were command line arguments.

The way you add the variables to Arguments is in the Expressions tab of the Execute Process Task Editor window:

1. On that tab, there's a "Misc" header and a blank Expressions field. Click into the field and a "..." button will show up. Click that
2. In the new window that appears, select Arguments as the Property, then click the "..." in this window's Expression field
3. Here, you need to set up the argument, including both your filepath and the variables you want to pass in, using the SSIS Expression syntax. Note that you'll need to escape "s and \s with a \ before each. You're shooting for something like this:

   ```
   "\"C:\\your_file_path_here\\your_script.py\" \"" + @[User::url] + "\" " + @[User::uid] + " " + @[User::pwd]
   ```

   You might need to quote your UID/PW fields as well depending on what characters are allowed in them.

Once you have that set up, those variables will pass into your script the same way any other command line argument would. You can tack an "import sys" at the top of your script and use sys.argv[0] for the URL, sys.argv[1] for the UID, and sys.argv[2] for the PW.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand you, but I will try to answer anyway.

My suggestion would be that you create multiple variables and with these variables make a new one, the final variable with all data.

Check screenshot and see what is my suggestion:

[image]

As you see, I marked with red squares where I put variables. Also, at bottom of picture check how I created variables.

**With this usage of variables, you can change value when you run package!**

Here is expression for `rTotal`:

```
"requests.get('https://jira.tpp.tsysecom.com/rest/zapi/latest/zql/executeSearch?zqlQuery=" + @[User::URL]  +
"', auth=HTTPBasicAuth(" + @[User::uid]  + ", " + @[User::pwd]  + ") , verify=False).json()"
```